# In r, get output values in power curve for 'a' and 'b' values

Tags: r, regression

I apologise for this basic question but i am truly stuck for whatever reason. I am hoping to get the output values from a power curve of 'a' and 'b' from y = a*x^b. Assuming i have this data set:

```
 x       y       log10(x)         log10(y)
 7      240     0.84509804      2.380211242
45      610     1.653212514     2.785329835
14      340     1.146128036     2.531478917
30      500     1.477121255     2.698970004
24      450     1.380211242     2.653212514
57      690     1.755874856     2.838849091
```

And it produces this graph in excel:
[image]

Using the excel example, how would i get the output values in `r` for a=2.465 and b=0.2401.

Comment: Use the function `nls`.

Comment: Your graph isn't graphing the numbers above. Post the correct graph, or show how you obtained this one.

Comment: I tried `nls` but I get this error:  `nls(x ~ A * y ^ B,start = list(A = 0, B = 0))`
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Comment: Use the log transformation to linearize and estimate initial parameter values for `nls`. Possibly wrap that in a `selfStart` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
DF <- read.table(text="x       y       log10(x)         log10(y)
7      240     0.84509804      2.380211242
45      610     1.653212514     2.785329835
14      340     1.146128036     2.531478917
30      500     1.477121255     2.698970004
24      450     1.380211242     2.653212514
57      690     1.755874856     2.838849091", header=TRUE)
```

Create a selfstarting model: 
(Disclaimer: The function names doesn't reflect my political attitude, it's merely in line with the naming scheme of selfstarting functions.)

```
SSpower <- selfStart(~ A*x^B,
                     function(mCall, data, LHS)
                     {
                       xy <- sortedXyData(mCall[["x"]], LHS, data)
                       if(nrow(xy) < 3) {
                         stop("Too few distinct x values to fit a power function")
                       }
                       z <- xy[["y"]]
                       xy[["logx"]] <- log(xy[["x"]])     
                       xy[["logy"]] <- log(xy[["y"]])  
                       aux <- coef(lm(logy ~ logx, xy))
                       pars <- c(exp(aux[[1]]), aux[[2]])
                       setNames(pars,
                                mCall[c("A", "B")])
                     }, c("A", "B"))
```

Use the selfstarting model for fitting:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ SSpower(x, A, B), data=DF)
```

Plot:

```
plot(y~x, data=DF)
lines(x=1:60, y=predict(fit, newdat=list(x=1:60)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roland. I have encountered a new problem however. I've placed this function in a loop (it loops 1000 times) and when i try to use the nls function, i get:
"Error in nls(y ~ SSpower[[j]][[i]](x,  : 
  number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
In addition: Warning message:
In nls(y ~ SSpower[[j]][[i]](x,  :
  No starting values specified for some parameters.
Initializing ‘A’, ‘B’ to '1.'.
Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model"

Answer (score 1):

`data` is your dataset:

```
y=data[,3]
x= data[,4]

nls(x ~ A * y ^ B)
Nonlinear regression model
  model: x ~ A * y^B
   data: parent.frame()
     A      B 
2.4635 0.2421 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.0008733

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.774e-06
```

Comment: I'm not interested in the values so much as interested in ascertaining the values. The values will be looped in a model that retrieves different 'a' and 'b' values in each loop and then calculates different results based on the different outputs of 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following (and make your problem reproducible next time. That wil probably also help you to point at the precise problem):

```
x  <-  c(7, 45, 14, 30, 24, 57)
y  <-  c(240, 610, 340, 500, 450, 690)

logx  <-  log10(x)
logy  <-  log10(y)

lm.000  <-  lm(logy ~ logx)
summary(lm.000)

coef(lm.000)[1]
coef(lm.000)[2]

plot(x, y)
curve(x^coef(lm.000)[2]*10^coef(lm.000)[1], add=TRUE, lwd=2)
```